# android Mediaplayer errors after update to 5.0

Tags: android

Just recently update my Galaxy s5 to 5.0 from 4.4.4 and my code for my media player is broken. Everything worked fine until the update, this also occurs on my nexus 7 tablet. Im getting a url from a server and am trying to stream an mp3 from the server. This code below is all done inside of an asynctask in the onpostexecute method.

```
        try
        {
            if (mediaPlayer == null)
            {
                mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
                mediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
                mediaPlayer.setDataSource(sUrl);
                mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(this);
                mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp)
        {
            mp.start();
        }
```

Here is my log

```
04-26 21:44:19.021    4660-4671/com.reach.sledgehammerlabs.reach   D/MediaHTTPConnection﹕ filterOutInternalHeaders: key=User-Agent, val=  Samsung   SAMSUNG-SM-G900A stagefright/Beyonce/1.1.9 (Linux;Android 5.0)
04-26 21:44:19.021    4660-4725/com.reach.sledgehammerlabs.reach   D/MediaHTTPConnection﹕ setReadTimeout with 30000ms
04-26 21:44:19.021    4660-4725/com.reach.sledgehammerlabs.reach I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
04-26 21:44:19.031    4660-4725/com.reach.sledgehammerlabs.reach I/System.out﹕ KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
04-26 21:44:19.171    4660-4674/com.reach.sledgehammerlabs.reach D/MediaHTTPConnection﹕ setReadTimeout with 30000ms
04-26 21:44:19.171    4660-4674/com.reach.sledgehammerlabs.reach I/System.out﹕ (HTTPLog)-Static: isSBSettingEnabled false
04-26 21:44:19.181    4660-4674/com.reach.sledgehammerlabs.reach I/System.out﹕ KnoxVpnUidStorageknoxVpnSupported API value returned is false
04-26 21:44:19.351    4660-4725/com.reach.sledgehammerlabs.reach V/MediaPlayer﹕ message received msg=100, ext1=1, ext2=-2147483648
04-26 21:44:19.351    4660-4725/com.reach.sledgehammerlabs.reach E/MediaPlayer﹕ error (1, -2147483648)
04-26 21:44:19.351    4660-4725/com.reach.sledgehammerlabs.reach V/MediaPlayer﹕ callback application
04-26 21:44:19.351    4660-4725/com.reach.sledgehammerlabs.reach V/MediaPlayer﹕ back from callback
04-26 21:44:19.351    4660-4660/com.reach.sledgehammerlabs.reach E/MediaPlayer﹕ Error (1,-2147483648)
```

Comment: Have you set api level to 21 in manifest?

Comment: It already is set to 21 as targeted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it wasn't always working was because some of the urls had spaces in them and they weren't handled correctly.

http://a space vs http://a%space

Answer (score 0):

I have meet the same question.Try

> setDataSource(context,Uri.parse(your url))

This solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

we faced same problem on  Galaxy s4 with 5.0 update, after trying many solutions we finally changed protocol of url from http to rtsp (e.g. "http://some/file/url" with "rtsp://some/file/url")and it resolved the issue